# Is it possible to include dependency app -from another repository- in a circleci build?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

**The problem**

I have a single repo project which I split it in 2 separate repos.
I split it because it was difficult to manage such a monolithic beast.
In both repos I have implemented circleci tests.

The tests in the first repo are failing because they depend on the existence of a second application which lives in the second repo. The circleci tests in the second repo run successfully.
In general, the first repo is a Flask app with a database and the second repo is an Flask-ElasticSearch-redis app/service.

I experimented with workflows, but I couldn’t make it work. When I SSH to the first’s repo circleci workspace, I couldn’t see any URLs related to the second app (using netstat), which is expected.

Is it possible to build and run the circleci tests of the first repo in a way that the build will include the second (dependency) app?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` from the repo that has the dependency and build both.

Comment: it would be great if it was so simple, git clone isn’t enough. The dependency app it’s an API, so it need its own stack to work.

Comment: Any idea if the dependency is already built in another repo with an artifact from circleCI?